# Button Animation in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I have the following code. There's two things I would like to fix:

1. When you click the submit button, you will see a **sudden color change**, how can I remove that? It looks like a glitchy animation. As soon as you click the submit button, you will see the sudden color change into something yellowish or whitish.
2. When you click the submit button, and the animation plays, I want the checkmark with the circle background to be displayed towards the left, or at the same place where the button is. Right now, the checkmark and the circle are displayed more towards the right, but how can I make it so I make them display the same place where the button is?

Any suggestions? Thanks

```js
var basicTimeline = anime.timeline({
  autoplay: false,
});

var pathEls = $(".check");
for (var i = 0; i < pathEls.length; i++) {
  var pathEl = pathEls[i];
  var offset = anime.setDashoffset(pathEl);
  pathEl.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", offset);
}

basicTimeline
  .add({
    targets: ".text",
    duration: 1,
    opacity: "0"
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".button",
    duration: 1200,
    height: 20,
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: "#D3D3D3",
    border: "0",
    borderRadius: 100
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".progress-bar",
    duration: 2000,
    width: 200,
    easing: "linear"
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".button",
    width: 0,
    duration: 1
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".progress-bar",
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    delay: 500,
    duration: 750,
    borderRadius: 80,
    backgroundColor: "#0563bb"
  })
  .add({
    targets: pathEl,
    strokeDashoffset: [offset, 0],
    duration: 200,
    easing: "easeInOutSine",
    complete: () =>
      setTimeout(() => $('#my-form').submit(), 100)
  });


$(".button").click(playButtonAnim);

$(".text").click(playButtonAnim);

function playButtonAnim() {
  basicTimeline.play();
}
```

```css
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

.shakingErr {
  border-color: red;
  animation: shake 0.82s forwards;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}


/* fancy button styles */

.buttonWrapper {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  background: #0563bb;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.text {
  font: .7rem;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-52%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0;
  left: 100px;
  top: 25%;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  background: #0563bb;
}

svg {
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 100px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.check {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.js">
</script>

<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="#" id="my-form" method="POST" novalidate>
            <div class='buttonWrapper'>
              <div class="button">
                <div class="text">Submit</div>
              </div>
              <div class="progress-bar"></div>
              <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 25 30" style="enable-background:new 0 0 25 30;">
                  <path class="check" class="st0" d="M2,19.2C5.9,23.6,9.4,28,9.4,28L23,2" />
                </svg>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

### update

the alignment near the bottom of the contact form is off right after the submit button, how can I fix this?

My output:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Aside from the issues, your HTML has some issues (which you can see in the syntax highlighter of the snippet editor) and you're also including jQuery 3 times, with 2 different versions. Add a single reference to 3.6.0 instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, what area in HTML is causing the syntax highlight issue? I cannot seem to find it

Comment: Please see [mcve].  Please only include the html/js/css that's *relevant* to the question and demonstrates the issue.   The process of reducing your css to only the *relevant* css may, in many case, provide you with your answer yourself.

Comment: Other tips: `float: center` isn't a thing, and floats in general are outdated as a layout strategy. Script elements should be placed _after_ the HTML for best loading experience.

Comment: I tried implementing the suggestions, but I'm still getting the syntax highlight issue

Comment: Reducing your js to identify the "yellow/pink" flash - remove all except the first .button timeline entry and increase duration.  You can see it's part of that anime.timeline.play.   Removing *all* the css and it doesn't happen, so that's the conflict.  So removing css until it stops happening (then putting that line back) gives:   https://jsfiddle.net/cm40wrho/  so the "yellow/pink" flash is caused by the anime.js as it transforms from blue to grey - that's just your choice of colours and the transition it takes.

Comment: Isnt there another way to fix this? I would like to keep the colors but stop the flash

Comment: It looks like the default easing is `easeInOutQuad` but is acting more like [easeInOutBack](https://easings.net/#easeInOutBack)- if you pump up the duration then inspect the element before you click it, you'll see the rgb goes right up to `rgb(253, 234, 216)` (or so), which is beyond the target of 211,211,211 - so the easing function "bounces" passed the required value then soothes back, giving your yellow flash.  The solution is to change the `easing` (eg `easing:'linear'`)

Comment: isnt it already set to linear though?

Comment: Clearly not.  Because if you set to linear then it doesn't give the yellow flash.  Did you not try it?

Comment: Just noticed: the document gives an example, not a default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played a little with your animation...

1. About the sudden color change, I made it change before the transformation occurs (button to progress-bar). It looks smoother now, IMO.
2. About the final position, I changed the CSS rule for `svg` about the `left` property AND added a `left: 26` to the `.progress-bar` last animation step.

```js
var basicTimeline = anime.timeline({
  autoplay: false,
});

var pathEls = $(".check");
for (var i = 0; i < pathEls.length; i++) {
  var pathEl = pathEls[i];
  var offset = anime.setDashoffset(pathEl);
  pathEl.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", offset);
}

basicTimeline
  .add({
    targets: ".text",
    duration: 1,
    opacity: "0"
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".button",
    duration: 100,
    backgroundColor: "#D3D3D3", // Change the color here.
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".button",
    duration: 1200,
    height: 20,
    width: 200,
    //backgroundColor: "#D3D3D3", // Not here!
    border: "0",
    borderRadius: 100
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".progress-bar",
    duration: 2000,
    width: 200,
    easing: "linear"
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".button",
    width: 0,
    duration: 1
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".progress-bar",
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    delay: 500,
    duration: 750,
    borderRadius: 80,
    backgroundColor: "#0563bb",
    left: 26  // Added to position at the left, aligned with the rest
  })
  .add({
    targets: pathEl,
    strokeDashoffset: [offset, 0],
    duration: 200,
    easing: "easeInOutSine",
    //complete: () =>
      //setTimeout(() => $('#my-form').submit(), 100) // Commented just to see the result longer...
  });


$(".button").click(playButtonAnim);

$(".text").click(playButtonAnim);

function playButtonAnim() {
  basicTimeline.play();
}
```

```css
/* Contact Form */

input[type=text],
[type=email],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
#subject:focus {
  background: var(--bgFormElsFocus);
  transform: scale(1.02);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.contactform {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.contactform:hover {
  animation-name: gradient;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.column {
  float: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column,
  input[type=submit] {
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

.shakingErr {
  border-color: red;
  animation: shake 0.82s forwards;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}


/* fancy button styles */

.buttonWrapper {
  height: 20px; /* For the button vertical alignement */
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0.9em;  /* For the button vertical alignement */
}

.button {
  background: #0563bb;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.text {
  font: .7rem;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-52%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0;
  left: 100px;
  top: 25%;
  border-radius: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  background: #0563bb;
}

svg {
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 26px; /* CHANGED - was 100px */
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.check {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.js">
  </script>
  <!--/script-->
  <!--script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
  </script-->
  <!--link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:600" rel="stylesheet"-->
  <!--script src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- start contact section -->
  <section id="contact">
    <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="contactform">
        <div style="text-align:center">
          <div class="section-title">
            <h2>
              <br/>Get In Touch
            </h2>
          </div>
          <p>Feel Free To Reach Out To Me Through This Form! </p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <form name="myform" action="#" id="my-form" method="POST" novalidate>
              <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="first name" name="firstname" placeholder="Your First Name.." required>
              <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your Last Name.." required>
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email.." required>
              <label for="subject">Subject</label>
              <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Lets Collaborate.." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
              <div class='buttonWrapper'>
                <div class="button">
                  <div class="text">Submit</div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 25 30" style="enable-background:new 0 0 25 30;">
                  <path class="check" class="st0" d="M2,19.2C5.9,23.6,9.4,28,9.4,28L23,2" />
                </svg>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End Contact Section -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you! This works! I just have one more small request, can you take a look at my updated post under `update`? I cannot seem to figure out this part

Comment: I don't get what is misaligned...

Comment: I edited the post with clear images. Please take a look

Comment: I edited with modifications to the CSS. Look for `.buttonWrapper` and `.button`.

Comment: hmm so is there a way that the top margin is the same as before, but the bottom margin is the only one thats changed? Because right now, everything seems to be sticking to top

Comment: specifically, the checkmark with the circle is sticking to the top

Comment: Ho loll... I see.

Comment: I edited again ;)

Comment: Bonus... I commented out some external ressources... You were loading jQuery thrice and the Poppins font twice. ;) Be carefull about that... As it may cause other strange issues. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var basicTimeline = anime.timeline({
  autoplay: false,
});

var pathEls = $(".check");
for (var i = 0; i < pathEls.length; i++) {
  var pathEl = pathEls[i];
  var offset = anime.setDashoffset(pathEl);
  pathEl.setAttribute("stroke-dashoffset", offset);
}

basicTimeline
  .add({
    targets: ".text",
    duration: 1,
    opacity: "0"
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".button",
    duration: 1,
    background: "#FFFFFF",
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".button",
    duration: 600,
    height: 20,
    width: 200,
    border: "0",
    background: "#D3D3D3",
    borderRadius: 100
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".progress-bar",
    duration: 2000,
    width: 200,
    easing: "linear"
  })
  .add({
    targets: ".button",
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    delay: 500,
    duration: 750,
    borderRadius: 80,
    backgroundColor: "#0563bb"
  })
  .add({
    targets: pathEl,
    strokeDashoffset: [offset, 0],
    duration: 200,
    easing: "easeInOutSine",
    complete: () =>
      setTimeout(() => $('#my-form').submit(), 100)
  });


$(".button").click(playButtonAnim);

$(".text").click(playButtonAnim);

function playButtonAnim() {
  basicTimeline.play();
}
```

```css
/* fancy button styles */

.buttonWrapper {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  background: #0563bb;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden
}

.text {
  font: .7rem;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progress-bar {
  position:absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 200px;
  background: #0563bb;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

svg {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.check {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.js">
</script>

<section id="contact">
  <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="contactform">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <form name="myform" action="#" id="my-form" method="POST" novalidate>
            <div class='buttonWrapper'>
              <div class="button">
                <div class="text">Submit</div>
              <div class="progress-bar"></div>
                          <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 25 30" style="enable-background:new 0 0 25 30;">
                  <path class="check" class="st0" d="M2,19.2C5.9,23.6,9.4,28,9.4,28L23,2" />
                </svg>
                            </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```